# How to Get Recently Viewed Products in Magento 2 Using Customer Entity Id

Tags: magento2, php, catalog, products

I want to display the **recently viewed** products name and products id of a particular customer **using customer entity id**.

How can I do that in Magento 2 programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can use default table `report_event` to get information about visited pages.

All product IDs saved at the column `object_id`, customer id saved at `subject_id`.

You need to get all records with `event_type_id == 1`(catalog_product_view)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply get recently viewed for the current user, this is easily achieve with the Viewed collection in reports ([much like in Mage 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36062139/1082555))

```
protected $recentlyViewed;

public function __construct(
...
    \Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Viewed $recentlyViewed
) {
...
    $this->recentlyViewed = $recentlyViewed;
}

/**
 * Get recently viewed products for the customer
 *
 */
public function getMostRecentlyViewed(){
    return $this->recentlyViewed->getItemsCollection();
}
```